# When trying to configure data guard broker I'm getting Error: ORA-16606: unable to find property ""

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, listener, dataguard, tnsnames

I'm trying to setup data guard broker in my production instance. I have duplicated the primary database to standby database successfully. I've added primary database to my configuration and when I'm trying to add standby database following error is getting

```
DGMGRL> add database 'orcl_standby' as connect identifier is orcl_standby 
maintained as physical;
Error: ORA-16606: unable to find property ""
Error: ORA-16554: translation not valid

Failed.
```

I think it is the issue with the connect identifier I have given. But I'm not able to troubleshoot that. Below is my tnsnames.ora of standby database.

```
ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.80.19)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SID = orcl)
      (UR = A)
    )
  )

ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = CLRExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

ORCL_STANDBY =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.80.16)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SID = orcl_standby)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl_standby)
      (UR = A)
    )
  )
```

Please help to troubleshoot this issue.

Comment: If this is related to TNS name configuration you would likely to hit ORA-12154. How did you create the configuration? Can you show us how did you add the primary database? I am sorry to doubt but are you sure you hit this error while adding standby database?

Comment: is orcl_standby the db_unique_name for the db? Additionally you should look for details in drc log (same location as alert log), it usually gives you much more information.

Comment: @JSapkota This is how I have added primary database:                    CREATE CONFIGURATION ORACL_dg_config AS PRIMARY DATABASE IS orcl CONNECT IDENTIFIER IS orcl;

Comment: @Raj Yes orcl_standby is the db_unique_name of the database

Comment: See if shortening the standby SID and/or service name length to 8 characters or less helps.

Comment: @mustaccio Sorry. It is not possible.

Comment: @JSapkota Is this any issue with log_archive_dest_state_2 ? Please help